# python function not returning the full name, it returns "Q Filio!" why is that?

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

```
def get_formatted_name(first_name, last_name):
    """---"""
    full_name = first_name + ' ' + last_name
    return full_name.title()

while True:
    print('\nPlease tell me your name:')
    print("(enter 'q' at any time to quit)")

    f_name = input('First name: ')
    if f_name == 'q':
            break

    l_name = input('Last name : ')
    if l_name == 'q':
            break

formatted_name = get_formatted_name(f_name, l_name)
print("\nHello, " + formatted_name + '!')
```

Comment: `"""---"""` what is this for? If you expect it to be printed before the "Hello, <name>!" statement, then you'll need to place that in a `print` statement accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The program will keep asking the user for his name until he inputs `'q'` either for the first name or for the last name. Then it will overwrite that name with `'q'` and treat that `'q'` as part of the name instead of the previously entered name.

You should move the last two lines inside the `while`:

```
def get_formatted_name(first_name, last_name):
    """---"""
    full_name = first_name + ' ' + last_name
    return full_name.title()

while True:
    print('\nPlease tell me your name:')
    print("(enter 'q' at any time to quit)")

    f_name = input('First name: ')
    if f_name == 'q':
            break

    l_name = input('Last name : ')
    if l_name == 'q':
            break

    formatted_name = get_formatted_name(f_name, l_name)
    print("\nHello, " + formatted_name + '!')
```

Then the output is as expected:

```
Please tell me your name:
(enter 'q' at any time to quit)
First name: a
Last name : b

Hello, A B!

Please tell me your name:
(enter 'q' at any time to quit)
First name: c
Last name : d

Hello, C D!

Please tell me your name:
(enter 'q' at any time to quit)
First name: q

Process finished with exit code 0
```